# How can you disable the "Enhanced Scrollbar" in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I don't want the Enhanced Scrollbar in Visual Studio 2017 - where it puts coloured markings in the scrollbar representations various states of code.

I can't find anything in options under Text Editor - in All Languages or C#. I also can't find anything in Google.

I really hope I can disable this feature - it's just a distraction for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars > Display. Or right click the scrollbar and select Scroll Bars Options.

Comment: thanks - i guess i missed the scroll bars section. right click is a nice touch too.

Comment: I've deselected 'Show annotations over vertical scroll bar', but all the coloured bars are still there. Is this a bug?I think it worked previously. (as we can see from my previous comment 6 years ago LMFAO)

Comment: I even deselect 'display horizontal or vertical scroll bar' and they still show. Looks like yet another bug.